# In how many ways can $9$ people be distributed into $3$ groups of $3$ people?

Tags: combinatorics

How can I distribute $9$ people in $3$ groups of $3$ people?
(The order of the groups and the order of the people doesn't matter).

I would like to know the procedure to solve it (the solution is 280).

Comment: Hi, MUG, and welcome to [Spanish.SE]. Note that your question is not about the Spanish language. Have you tried posting it in [Mathematics.SE]? You will get much better advice there. Nonetheless I recommend you to read the [help], [tour] and [ask] sections to get a grasp about how these sites work. Please come back for any questions regarding the Spanish language you may have! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Imagine lining all the people up so you can break the line into the first three, the second three, and the third three.  There are $9!$ ways to do that.  You get equivalent groups if you scramble the first three people in any order, so we divide by $3!$.  You can also independently scramble the second three or third three, which gives two more divisions by $3!$.  Finally, you can reorder the groups of three in $3!$ ways, so the final answer is 
$$\frac {9!}{(3!)^4}=280$$